# Find how Android App was started in Application class

Tags: java, android

Very simple set up:

- Extended Application class with `onCreate()` method.
- One `Activity`
- One `IntentService` scheduled to run as repeating from time to time by `AlarmManager`

Application class will be instantiated in 2 cases here:

1. When activity is launched directly (and app was dead)
2. When IntentService is started by AlarmManager's pending intent (in case app was dead)

Now question:
In Application class how to get which of the 2 cases above started app?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way for you to tell which of those two cases caused your process to start, from within `onCreate()` of the custom `Application` subclass.

Comment: Uh, so quick and @CommonsWare himself, Im very pleased :) and also sad as this means there is no solution to this :(

Comment: I am not quite certain why you would need to determine the difference anyway. `onCreate()` of `Application` is called on the main application thread, and so you do not want to do anything slow there regardless of what component triggered the process creation. If the work that you want to do is fast, you might just do it all the time, or else move that logic into the `Activity` or `IntentService`.

Comment: Yes I will have to change a logic,needed some initialisation done only once and only when not started by particular service, just was thinking it is possible.

Comment: @CommonsWare and btw why not to add it as an answer? "This-is-Not-possible" type of answers are answers too as I understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way for you to tell which of those two cases caused your process to start, from within `onCreate()` of the custom `Application` subclass. `Application` has no `heyWhatStartedMe()` sort of method to call, nor is `onCreate()` passed anything that indicates the reason for the process to have been started.

I am not quite certain why you would need to determine the difference anyway. `onCreate()` of `Application` is called on the main application thread, and so you do not want to do anything slow there regardless of what component triggered the process creation. If the work that you want to do is fast, you might just do it all the time, or else move that logic into the `Activity` or `IntentService`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Add extras to your intent inside `IntentService`  and check them inside your MainActivity.

Put an `int` which is your id into the new `Intent`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("key", 1); //Your id
intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Then grab the id in your new `Activity`:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
int value = -1; // or other values
if(b != null)
    value = b.getInt("key");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but looks like you completely missed the question. Intent service has nothing to do with Activity. Its all about Application class.

Comment: Don't you start your activity from the intentservice?

Comment: Nope, service doing its own stuff not connected to activity